# Can't use PIL in Python when the script is inside of the Windows Startup-folder

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, window, python-imaging-library

**I am trying to make a simple python script that is not working when it is in the folder: "C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup" in windows 10**

So I have made a python script without console (.pyw), which is run when the pc starts and the user has logged in. After that, a Tkinter fullscreen topmost window will appear with an image on it. The script has to be in the Startup-folder to run when the user has started the pc and logged in. Inside the startup-folder is also a .jpg image which is the one that should be showing.

The problem is that if I run the script manually from inside the Startup-folder everything works, but when I restart the pc and log in, the Tkinter window doesn't open, and instead the Windows image viewer program opens up showing the desired picture, but not a Tkinter window.

This is probably because if I run this code inside the folder by manually double clicking the script I get this result:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path.cwd() #Should give the file path from C: to the running script
```

> C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup

While if I keep this script in the folder and restart the pc instead I get this result:

> C:/WINDOWS/System32

This must mean that when I run the script manually it will run via the first file path, while if I restart the PC it runs it through another file path. This might be somehow interfering with my code.

The reason why the Windows image viewer program shows the image has maybe something to do with .show(), which is the line of code that opens the Windows image viewer program to show the image with the variable name .

**This is the code with added comments:**

```
import tkinter as tk # Importing Tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image # Importing Image functions from PIL

root = tk.Tk() # Making a Tkinter window with the name root

root.attributes('-fullscreen',1) # Making the window fullscreen
root.attributes('-topmost',True) # Making the window topmost
root.title('<irrelevant>') 

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Image.png') # Code line taken from the internet, supposed to turn the image into a variable of the type that Tkinter use, this is the code line that is causing the problem

label = tk.Label(root, image=image) # Placeing the image on the screen
label.image = image
label.place(x=<irrelevant>, y=<irrelevant>)

root.mainloop() # Running the screen
```

Note that this is not copy-pasted code but written by eye so that the spelling errors here might not be in the original script, another note is that this script runs perfectly if you have it anywhere but the startup folder, for example, if you have it on your desktop you can successfully run the script.

I have tried to eliminate this problem for the better part of a day but have been unsuccessful.

I have tried changing

```
ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Image.png'))
```

to

```
file = 'Image.png'
tk.PhotoImage(file=file)
```

to no avail.

I've tried to change the whole thing from using Tkinter to using Pygame, but it just made things more complex, especially to replace the "topmost" line with Pygame.

I have also looked into other ways to make a script run on Windows startup, but they all have seemed unnecessarily complicated.

I do not need a small fix to the code, I just need a script to fulfill the task mentioned earlier, even if that means using different libraries or solving the problem in another way.

Comment: Try adding this at the start of the file: `import os; os.chdir("C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup")`. It changes the working directory to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: @TheLizzard changing the working directory before opening the image made the script open Tkinter! **But** it still opened the regular Windows image viewer program to view the image, so first I get the Tkinter window over everything, but when I close it, it still shows the image but now in the Image viewer?

Comment: Realized that the reason why the Windows image viewer program opens up the picture is that the picture is in the Startup-file, meaning that the PC tries to execute that image but instead just opened it. it has nothing to do with my script since if I delete my script and just have the pic inside the file I still get it opened. I can solve this by changing the .chdir to some other place where the picture is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found one solution:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from os import chdir

chdir('C:/Users/<UserName>/<CustomFolderName>')

root = tk.Tk
root.attributes('-fullscreen',1)
root.attributes('-topmost',True)
root.title('<title>')

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('<Image>.<format>'))

label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
label.image = image
label.place(x=<x-coordinates>, y=<y-coordinates>)

root.mainloop()
```

Where the script is: 'C:/Users/<UserName>/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup/<Script>.pyw'

And the image: 'C:/Users/<UserName>/<CustomFolderName>/<Image>.<format>'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make a shortcut to command `pythonw c:/path_to_script/script.pyw` and place it to Startup folder.

Comment: What do you mean by `label`? This question has the `tkinter` tag so do you mean `tkinter.Label`?

Comment: No, no, I mean to run script by running "pythonw c:/path_to_script/script.pyw" command from label (shortcut) or bat file. (ie make shortcut to pythonw and add "c:/path_to_script/script.pyw" as a parameter).

Comment: What do you mean by using a shortcut command? Do I make another file inside the Startup-folder and have it contain "pythonw <path to script>" and what file format if so? Or do I make a windows shortcut?

Comment: Yes, i mean windows shortcut. Go to Startup folder, from context menu make shortcut and for object location print "pythonw <path to script>".

Answer (score 0):

[@Hamligt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816950/14145370) does work, but if the username/startup location is unknown, and the script is placed in the startup folder, you can instead `chdir` into the script's folder, avoiding hard-coded values, thus making it work on any computer.

```py
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
print(os.getcwd()) # correct folder
```

Why this code works is because without the full path of the image, it is read from the current working directory, which is wrong, so we need to manually correct it back.

Comment: This is also a solution. You can also use the environ function to retrieve the current windows users username and format it into the directory path, but even though that would work on most computers, some might have slightly different directory paths for things, and therefore this might suit better in most cases.

Comment: @Hamligt Yes, (correct me if I'm wrong) I think there's only such thing as a startup folder for Windows, and I don't think you can change the path, so using the `%userprofile%` environment variable would also work (`%username%` would **NOT** because if you change your username, the `%userprofile%` path doesn't change but `%username%` does.)